# Install Flash Player 11.9 on case-sensitive filesystem

Tags: install, adobe-flash

I'm trying to install Flash Player 11.9 on Mac OS X running on a case-sensitive filesystem. The installation fails with a (very unsatisfactory) error message.

What can I do to complete the installation successfully?

Answer (score 1):

As I posted on an [Adobe forum post](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5847023#5847023) the reason is the following: The installation tries to access `/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy` but the correct spelling is `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`. You can execute the following commands in a terminal to solve the problem and successfully complete the installation:

```
cd /usr/libexec
sudo ln -s PlistBuddy Plistbuddy
```